# Auto Login not working unless keyboard is plugged in

Tags: lightdm, auto-login

- I want to use Ubuntu with Unity (11.10) in a kiosk computer (touchscreen all-in-one pc).
- I want to use touchscreen for all user input (like ATM).
- During Installation I have created only one account and enabled auto Login.
- It will only login automatically when the keyboard is connected

Please help

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this sounds more like a bug.  Did you file a bug in Launchpad?